# should a dell optiplex 170l support one memory module?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, dell-optiplex

I am setting up a Dell Optiplex 170l for a friend.
Currently the system is running 256 MB for Windows XP.  I would like to get them a 1 GB module.

I am not sure from the documentation website if the PC will support only one chip?:

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/op170l/en/ug/specs.htm

Note: I am looking at one chip because the cost it all mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Optiplex 170L specs from that page says it should be able to. The "Memory Capacities" subsection says it can support a range of different memory modules (128-, 256-, 512-MB, or 1-GB), and the minimum memory for 1 module should be 128 MB. Buying them a 1GB memory module should be fine.